# exporting a text with double quotes

Tags: python, html, double-quotes

I'm pretty new to python and I'm facing the problem below.
I'm importing an xls file in python that in one of the columns has :

```
<a   href="myhyperlink"   target='_blank' >text displayed</a>
```

After I 'm processing the file I need to export it to a .txt file.
when I'm using this line:

```
file_to_export.to_csv('my/path' +"nameofthefile.txt", header=True, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep='\t')
```

I get the following error:

> need to escape, but no escapechar set

When I remove `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` argument my file is being exported without any errors but in the column mentioned above all `"` are doubled:

```
"<a   href=""myhyperlink""   target=""_blank"" >text displayed</a>"
```

I checked the intermediate steps and these extra `"` are not there.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: The CSV format requires that the quotes are doubled. A single quote would indicate the end of the string. Have you tried opening the resulting CSV file with, say, Open Office? Do the results look OK there?

Comment: double qoutes are correct - it information for tools which will read it as it is quote inside text, not end of text. Use `pandas.read_csv` or module `csv` (or even `OpenOffice`, `LibreOffice`) and they will read it correctly and you will get text with single quotes inside text. Python uses `\"` to put quote inside text - `"  \"  "`, CSV uses `""` for the same purpose - `"   ""   "`.

Comment: You're passing a delimiter of `\t`. Does your data contain `\t`? The "need to escape" implies that it does. You could strip/replace them before exporting, or pass `escapechar='\\'` or similar to escape them